# calculating $E(X_{(i)}| \sum_{i=1}^5 X_i)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

suppose 5.5,3.5, 2.5,4.5,2 be a random sample from of gamma distribution with parameters of $ \beta,\alpha=2$. if $Z_{(i)}$ be i-th order statistic a random sample of size 5 from $\Gamma(2,1)$, how can I calculate $E(X_{(i)}| \sum_{i=1}^5 X_i)$

Comment: You better write $\mathbb E(X_{(i)}\mid\sum_{j=1}^5 X_j)$ (or $\mathbb E(X_{(j)}\mid\sum_{i=1}^5 X_i)$). In your expression $i$ has a double role, wich is confusing.

Comment: What is the difference between $Z_i$ and $X_i$?